# Bootstrap4: collapse in grid system

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, grid

When showing a collapse from the first row (1, 2, 3), it shifts the other cards to the end of the one shown. Why is that happening and is there a way to prevent that?

I'd like the vertical groups (1&4, 2&5, 3&6) to act independently. For example, when showing collapse1, collapse2 and collapse3 shall stay at their default `start-positions`.

https://www.codeply.com/p/KDvhVI3QAM

CSS:

```css
.vertical-group {
    display:inline-block;
    width: 33%;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none!important;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<span class='vertical-group'>

    <div class='col-12'>
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header'>
                <a 
                    data-toggle='collapse' 
                    href='#collapseExample' 
                    role='button' 
                    aria-expanded='false' 
                    aria-controls='collapseExample'
                >Collapse1</a>
            </div>
            <div class='collapse' id='collapseExample'>  
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consectetur est eros, at cursus mauris molestie non. Nullam suscipit leo in volutpat eleifend. Mauris non mauris mauris. Nunc interdum lectus ipsum, vel scelerisque orci condimentum non. Integer pellentesque molestie posuere. Integer et placerat sapien. Quisque porttitor pretium mattis. Proin pretium fringilla velit, ac suscipit nisi maximus id. Mauris eget risus et quam maximus maximus a quis quam. Vestibulum lacinia nunc quis neque vulputate, at pretium augue sodales. Maecenas pulvinar diam arcu, id porta dui congue vehicula. In rhoncus ex in nunc rhoncus, nec semper orci consequat. Sed vitae metus nec erat rhoncus viverra. Aliquam vitae ex metus. Duis vehicula leo enim, a dictum justo condimentum quis. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='col-12'>
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header'>
                <a 
                    data-toggle='collapse' 
                    href='#collapseExample4' 
                    role='button' 
                    aria-expanded='false' 
                    aria-controls='collapseExample4'
                >Collapse4</a>
            </div>
            <div class='collapse' id='collapseExample4'>  
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <p>Duis vulputate est ut nulla pulvinar viverra. Fusce ultrices orci diam, ac suscipit lectus posuere eu. Proin ut cursus eros. In rhoncus tortor lacus, ac lobortis enim suscipit in. Nunc id consequat neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus scelerisque orci quis ligula vestibulum ornare. Vestibulum blandit pretium lacus at pulvinar.  </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</span>

<span class='vertical-group'>

    <div class='col-12'>
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header'>
                <a 
                    data-toggle='collapse' 
                    href='#collapseExample1' 
                    role='button' 
                    aria-expanded='false' 
                    aria-controls='collapseExample1'
                >Collapse2</a>
            </div>
            <div class='collapse' id='collapseExample1'>  
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <p>Duis vulputate est ut nulla pulvinar viverra. Fusce ultrices orci diam, ac suscipit lectus posuere eu. Proin ut cursus eros. In rhoncus tortor lacus, ac lobortis enim suscipit in. Nunc id consequat neque. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus scelerisque orci quis ligula vestibulum ornare. Vestibulum blandit pretium lacus at pulvinar.  </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
         <div class='col-12'>
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header'>
                <a 
                    data-toggle='collapse' 
                    href='#collapseExample5' 
                    role='button' 
                    aria-expanded='false' 
                    aria-controls='collapseExample5'
                >Collapse5</a>
            </div>
            <div class='collapse' id='collapseExample5'>  
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <p>Nunc ornare felis egestas sodales ornare. Mauris auctor suscipit nisi. Vestibulum varius mi cursus, luctus metus in, fringilla odio. In nec pellentesque eros, a pretium ligula. Quisque venenatis convallis ipsum, consequat tristique erat pulvinar nec. Sed ex odio, accumsan sit amet semper sit amet, consequat feugiat nisi. Fusce risus nibh, maximus quis aliquam sollicitudin, rhoncus sit amet enim. Vestibulum luctus elit tincidunt, suscipit enim vel, scelerisque arcu. Nunc bibendum lobortis est, in venenatis erat auctor a. Curabitur ac magna massa. Duis commodo facilisis rhoncus. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</span>

<span class='vertical-group'>    

    <div class='col-12'>
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header'>
                <a 
                    data-toggle='collapse' 
                    href='#collapseExample3' 
                    role='button' 
                    aria-expanded='false' 
                    aria-controls='collapseExample3'
                >Collapse3</a>
            </div>
            <div class='collapse' id='collapseExample3'>  
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <p>Nunc ornare felis egestas sodales ornare. Mauris auctor suscipit nisi. Vestibulum varius mi cursus, luctus metus in, fringilla odio. In nec pellentesque eros, a pretium ligula. Quisque venenatis convallis ipsum, consequat tristique erat pulvinar nec. Sed ex odio, accumsan sit amet semper sit amet, consequat feugiat nisi. Fusce risus nibh, maximus quis aliquam sollicitudin, rhoncus sit amet enim. Vestibulum luctus elit tincidunt, suscipit enim vel, scelerisque arcu. Nunc bibendum lobortis est, in venenatis erat auctor a. Curabitur ac magna massa. Duis commodo facilisis rhoncus. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class='col-12'>
        <div class='card'>
            <div class='card-header'>
                <a 
                    data-toggle='collapse' 
                    href='#collapseExample6' 
                    role='button' 
                    aria-expanded='false' 
                    aria-controls='collapseExample6'
                >Collapse6</a>
            </div>
            <div class='collapse' id='collapseExample6'>  
                <div class='card-body'>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consectetur est eros, at cursus mauris molestie non. Nullam suscipit leo in volutpat eleifend. Mauris non mauris mauris. Nunc interdum lectus ipsum, vel scelerisque orci condimentum non. Integer pellentesque molestie posuere. Integer et placerat sapien. Quisque porttitor pretium mattis. Proin pretium fringilla velit, ac suscipit nisi maximus id. Mauris eget risus et quam maximus maximus a quis quam. Vestibulum lacinia nunc quis neque vulputate, at pretium augue sodales. Maecenas pulvinar diam arcu, id porta dui congue vehicula. In rhoncus ex in nunc rhoncus, nec semper orci consequat. Sed vitae metus nec erat rhoncus viverra. Aliquam vitae ex metus. Duis vehicula leo enim, a dictum justo condimentum quis. </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [flex box](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to achieve that:

```html
<div class="vertical-groups">
    <div class="vertical-group">
        <div class="card" />
        <div class="card" />
    </div>
    <div class="vertical-group" />
    <div class="vertical-group" />
</div>
```

You can set `.vertical-groups` as the flex box container:

```css
.vertical-groups {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

`align-items: flex-start` is the key to ensure that the vertical direction starts from the top.

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/07hfmbo5/10/

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm, exactly what I was asking for.